# How do I select all text contained in <pre> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, selection

I have a contentEditable iframe with line numbers and text. The line numbers are contained in a div and all text is in a `<pre>`-element.

It looks like this:

```
<body>

  <div id="line_numbers">
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>
  </div>

  <pre>
    Text
  </pre>

</body>
```

Now, when someone presses Ctrl+A everything is selected, including the line numbers. I would like to change this behaviour to only include the contents of the `<pre>`.

I have set up a function that captures Ctrl+A and prevents the default operation. Now, how do I set the selection to contain everything within the `<pre>`?

Comment: have you tried $('pre').text() in jQuery?

Comment: To clarify, Christoffer is trying to *select* the text in the browser (for copy/paste purposes), not get the text string as a variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse/987376#987376) will help you out I think; you should be able to select the pre element using jQuery and pass it into the function supplied:

```
SelectText($('pre')[0]);
```

Comment: Deprecated browser function in Jquery

Answer (score -2):

Have you `$("#iframe_id").contents().find('pre').text()`?